# Restore database without overriding Auto growth

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, auto-growth

I created a database with auto growth 200MB. After restoring database auto growth changed to 1MB. Because my Backup file database auto growth is 1MB.

Is there a way to restore without overriding the auto growth ?

Comment: Can you repeat this with a fresh backup and confirm? When you restore from a backup it should use whatever file settings the db had at the time the backup was taken.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this in SQL 2016 (13.0.4001.0). Restore retain the auto-growth setting of the database (for which backup was taken).  Here is the code I tested with. 
Create database

```
CREATE DATABASE [AutoGrowTest]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'AutoGrowTest', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AutoGrowTest.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'AutoGrowTest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AutoGrowTest_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
```

Change auto-growth

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AutoGrowTest] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'AutoGrowTest', SIZE = 262144KB , FILEGROWTH = 131072KB )
GO
```

[image]
Backup database

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AutoGrowTest] TO  DISK = N'C:\AutoGrowthTestFull.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'AutoGrowTest-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Restore with diff name

```
USE [master] 

RESTORE DATABASE [AutoGrowTest_restore] FROM DISK = N'C:\AutoGrowthTestFull.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1, move N'AutoGrowTest' TO 
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AutoGrowTest_restore.mdf'
, move N'AutoGrowTest_log' TO 
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AutoGrowTest_restore_log.ldf'
, nounload, stats = 5 

GO
```

It retained auto-growth setting of original database.

[image]

Please note auto-growth setting changed in SQL 2016 than what is mentioned in some comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a database with auto growth 200MB. After restoring database
>   auto growth changed to 1MB. Because my Backup file database auto
>   growth is 1MB.

The initial settings for auto-growth are set to the default values when defining a new database. These defaults are established by using the auto-growth settings on the `model database` files.

The default auto-growth setting for the data file is `1 MB` with unrestrictive growth, and the log file is set to grow by 10% with unrestricted growth. If you haven’t tweaked your `model database settings` then you will have the same default auto-growth setting.

For You Ref [SQL Server Database Growth and Autogrowth Settings](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/)

Comment: However... if you restore from a backup the file size and properties should be the same as set for the user db. Not what is set for the model.